# Как получить значение атрибута?

Tags: java, servlet, атрибуты

Пишу веб-сервис с использованием servlet, freemarker, jetty, hibernate, mysql.

Есть два желаемых post-запроса: "**Добавить источник**" и "**Удалить источник**"

Но появляется загвоздка, объясняю по ходу дальше.

Есть такая форма

```
 <form action="/admin" method="post">
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1" name="sourceIp">
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1">IP...</label>
        </div>

        <div class="mdl-dialog__actions mdl-dialog__actions--full-width">
            <button type="submit" class="mdl-button" value="Add" ">Add source</button>
            <button type="submit" class="mdl-button" value="Delete">Delete source</button>
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">Disagree</button>
        </div>
 </form>
```

В ней есть две кнопки, которые отвечают за отправку формы.

Но каждая из них обращается к методу `doPost()` в сервлете и соответственно выполняются одинаковые операции.

Для того чтобы обойти это, решил, что стоит сделать выборку по атрибуту нажатой кнопки.

Т.е. нажимаем на "Add..." идет запрос в сервелет в метод `doPost()` и в нем ifами делаю выборку. Если пользователь нажал по кнопки с атрибутом `value=Add` то делаю одни операции с введенными данными, иначе другие.

Вопрос в следующем, как мне получить атрибут кнопки, по которой кликнул пользователь? 
Есть метод `getAttribute("value");` но не могу понять какой атрибут из всех он берет и как работает(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mdl-dialog__actions mdl-dialog__actions--full-width">
    <button type="submit" class="mdl-button" name="clickAdd" value="Add">Add source</button>
    <button type="submit" class="mdl-button" name="clickDelete" value="Delete">Delete source</button>
    <button type="button" class="mdl-button close" name="clickDisagree" value="Disagree">Disagree</button>
</div>
```

**Внутри сервлета:**

```
...
if(request.getParameter(clickAdd)!=null) System.out.println("Ты кликнул ADD");
else if(request.getParameter(clickDelete)!=null) System.out.println("Ты кликнул Delete");
...
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)